# Unexpected behaviour of numprint command

Tags: numprint

I am using the `numprint` package. This package is basically great, but sometimes it shows unexpected behaviour. Here is an example of such a case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numprint}
\begin{document}

\nprounddigits{1}
\numprint{.9869}

\nprounddigits{2}
\numprint{.9869}

\nprounddigits{3}
\numprint{.9869}

\nprounddigits{1}
\numprint{.8666}

\nprounddigits{2}
\numprint{.8666}

\nprounddigits{3}
\numprint{.8666}

\end{document}
```

The result looks like

> 0,0
>
> 0,99
>
> 0,987
>
> 0,9
>
> 0,87
>
> 0,867

Clearly, the first result is wrong. It should be "1,0". (Here, the the decimal sign is "," by default.) On the other hand, all the other results look correct.

Am I missing anything or is this a know bug? Are there any work around to avoid this issue? I need to print a tons of numbers with using \nprounddigits{1}, which can cause the present issue.

On Fedora 24, I am using pdfTeX Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2016/dev) that uses /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/numprint/numprint.sty.

Comment: I have found that \numprint{0.9869} results in "1,0" when \nprounddigits{1}. But, adding "0" to the original numbers seem unrealistic because some of them do not start with ".", e.g., "10.23".

Comment: Hmmm, I get "11,0" from `\nprounddigits{1}\numprint{10.9869}`, "10,2" from `\nprounddigits{1}\numprint{10.23}`, and "1,0" from `\nprounddigits{1}\numprint{0.9869}`. All three seem correct.

Comment: @Mico Can you see the same wrong result? That is, did you get "0,0" from \nprounddigits{1}\numprint{.9869}? I am afraid of the failure of my own environment.

Comment: Please check out Werner's answer and my comment below it: To get the correct results, you *must not* write `\numprint{.9869}`; instead, you must write either `\numprint{0.9869}` or `\numprint{0,9869}`.

Comment: It is obviously a bug, so you should try to contact the author.

Answer (score 11):

I agree this is a bug in `numprint`, but I'd use `siunitx` in any case: a quick 'compatibility' definition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\NewDocumentCommand\numprint{m}{\num[round-mode = places]{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand \nprounddigits{m}
  {\sisetup{round-precision = #1}}
\begin{document}

\nprounddigits{1}%
\numprint{.9869}

\nprounddigits{2}%
\numprint{.9869}

\nprounddigits{3}%
\numprint{.9869}

\nprounddigits{1}%
\numprint{.8666}

\nprounddigits{2}%
\numprint{.8666}

\nprounddigits{3}%
\numprint{.8666}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for giving a fantastic resolution! I compiled the above source and obtained the "correct" results. (I think the first number should be ".9869" instead of ",9869", although the latter case also resulted in the correct result, that is, "1.0". )

Answer (score 5):

The main problem here is that you're missing a prepended `0`:

> 1,0
>   0,99
>   0,987
>   0,9
>   0,87
>   0,867

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{numprint}

\begin{document}

\nprounddigits{1}%
\numprint{0.9869}

\nprounddigits{2}%
\numprint{0.9869}

\nprounddigits{3}%
\numprint{0.9869}

\nprounddigits{1}%
\numprint{0.8666}

\nprounddigits{2}%
\numprint{0.8666}

\nprounddigits{3}%
\numprint{0.8666}

\end{document}
```

If you're *only* printing decimals and may *never* have a prepended `0`, you can *always* include it by adding

```
\let\oldnumprint\numprint
\renewcommand{\numprint}[1]{\oldnumprint{0#1}}
```

after loading [`numprint`](http://ctan.org/pkg/numprint).

Comment: +1. Actually, what seems to make the difference is not the presence of `,` as the input decimal marker, but of the prefix `0` before either `,` or `.`

Comment: @Werner Thank you for considering this issue. As Mico points out, the problem is not caused by the symbol of the decimal sign. Actually, even if the symbol is changed to "." by \npdecimalsign{.}, the result of  "\nprounddigits{1} \numprint{.9869}" is still "0.0".

Comment: @ToruTakahashi - You may have misunderstood my comment: To get the correct output, it's necessary to provide `0` as the prefix to `.9869`, i.e., to write `0.9869`.

Comment: @Mico Well, I might have misunderstood you. I agree to prefix '0' to the  '.9869' in order to get the correct result "1,0". However, in my situation, providing '0' to the numbers less than one in "0.xxx..." format is difficult because there are a lot of numbers to be printed. Thank you.